# Unix shell script to remove blank lines following opening brackets

Tags: unix, vim, shell, sed, awk

I need a (sed, awk) shell script or, even better, a Vim command to remove any blank lines following a line with a single opening curly bracket. For example,

```
void func()
{


    foo();
}

void bar()
{

    helloWorld();
}
```

should become

```
void func()
{
    foo();
}

void bar()
{
    helloWorld();
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk 'NF{f=0}/^ *{/{ f=1 } f==1 && !NF{next}1' file
void func()
{
    foo();



}
```

A bit of explanation:

1. `/^ *{/` means search for 0 or more blank spaces before the first `{`.
2. Then set a flag to true (`f=1`).
3. When the next line is read and `f` is true and `!NF` (means there is no fields, i.e., the line is blank), skip line using `next`.
4. When the next line which is not a blank line (i.e., `NF{f=0}` means toggle back the flag), the rest of the lines will not be affected until the next opening brace.

Comment: @ghostdog74: removes the blank lines after opening brackets, but also all other blank lines...

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm still trying to figure out, looking at the gawk manpage, how it works though...

Comment: @andreas: I don't think you'll find that last "1" in the man page or the info file.

Answer (score 3):

Vim:

```
:%s/^{\(\n\s*\)*/{\r    /g
```

Comment: Would add a ^ before the 1st {.

Comment: maybe can be improved to take care of one single { on a line but there are blanks/spaces in front.

Comment: Something like this, I think: `:%s/^\(\s*{\)[\s\n]*/\1\r/`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest way of doing that in Vim is the following
substitution:

```
:%s/^\s*{\n\zs\_s*\n//
```

Comment: Don't you want `:%s/^\(\s*{\)\%(\s*\n\)*/\1\r/` so that you don't eliminate the spaces in front of the `{`?

Comment: @kejadlen: The command in the answer does not eliminate the spaces in front of the opening braces, because of the `\zs` specifier in the pattern, which sets the start of the match for substitution purposes right after the newline following the brace, thus keeping all matched characters prior to that point in tact (see `:help /\zs`).

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I wanted to figure this out using vim's global command:

```
:g /{/ s/\n\+/\r/
```

which is pretty darned short. I hope it works! :-)